# Layouts in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout

I´m trying to create layouts in ZF1

application.ini

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.layout.layout = "default"
```

Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initView() 
{ 
   $this->bootstrap('layout'); 
   $layout = $this->getResource('layout'); 
   $view = $layout->getView(); 
   $view->headTitle('default title');
   return $view; 
}
```

and i have two modules (home and test) the "default" layout is working in home but not in test (both are equals, just doing this to learn ZF1) 
Should i do something different to setup the default layout to all my modules?

Just in case you need it. this is the code for modules/test/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Test_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

}
```

and this is the code in modules/test/views/scripts/index.phtml

```
Hello, this is the test module
```

Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was not a layout issue. was a code issue in the view.